# differentiate between iPhones and iPads

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile, navigation

I'm working on my mobile site, I already have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        document.location = "android.html";
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

which diverts android users away from the current page on to androids own dedicated page.

what I would like to do is the same thing but for an iphone / ipad. I would like iphone / ipod touch to land on iphone.html and ipad to land on ipad.html displaying different content for both. How can I do this?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just expand your current approach to the other user agents:

```
var iphone = ((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod')))?true:false;
var ipad = (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad'))?true:false;
if(iphone){
 document.location = 'iphone.html';
}
if(ipad){
 document.location = 'ipad.html';
}
```